# Скрипт автоматического перехода на страницу внутри BODY

Tags: html, javascript

Доброго всем времени суток господа. Второй раз за сегодня

В инете полно разных скриптов автоматического перехода по нужной ссылке. Часть из них нужно совать между тегами HEAD ( да и пусть будет так ) , кое что можно прописать прямо в BODY.

Можно ли написать такой скрипт, что бы его можно было использовать только внутри BODY ? ( **Нет тоже ответ** )

p.s. прописать не лень, интересует будет ли так корректно работать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
location="ti_ploho_guglil.php" 
</script>
```

Comment: работает. но код подозрительно короткий O_o

Answer (score 1):

Если просто обеспечить, что скрипт не работает в `head`, то можно такой строкой:

```
document.body.any;
```

Если нужно проверить, где находится скрипт, то можно так:

```
document.querySelector('body script')
```

Если он будет в `head`, то результатом будет `null`, если в `body`, то нет.

Естественно, оба этих кода предполагают исполнение непосредственно в скрипте вне любых асинхронных операций, в том числе без ожидания завершения загрузки документа.

Answer (score 0):

задать ***window.location*** как-то так:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>перенаправил</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
        window.location = "/T4D/index.222.php" 
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```